# iOs app review - virtual currency

Tags: currency

I develop a trivia ios app and put virtual currency in. In my app, you will be able to buy virtual coins (consumable IAP), or get some when you win a game. With this coins, you can buy some non consumable items (questions packs, for example) by downloading it from our serveur. Do you think this kind of mechanisms are allowed by apple?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are only allowed to use Apple's in-app purchase https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: I think you should be okay. We're doing something similar on the game I'm working on. It's important to note that this question is off-topic though. It might serve you well to take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Angry Birds with Friends allows it. This is a question for Apple Developer support as we dont make that call, Apple does. The way they did it was they have in-App Purchases but you can choose to buy those with points you earned as well called "coins"